# Dynamically Allocating Stucture

Tags: json, go

I have a struct:

```
type person struct{
    FirstN      [10]byte
    Last Name   [10]byte
    Address     [15]byte
    zip         [6]byte
}
```

Then I have Map

```
   xyz = [01:aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccc123456]
```

This map is exactly the same as my struct. Basically if I overlay my structure with the string in the map it is an exact match.

I am trying to get a JSON string for this data, using Marshal. But for that (as I understand it) I need to update the data in the map into the struct and then pass the structure pointer to Marshal

But I cannot find any way to get the data from the map with key '01' which is a string and initialize my structure with it. I do not want to add a code to update each field in the structure by parsing the string from the map. Is there a way to do it or hardcoding is the only option.

Also is there a way to create a JSON string from a map string directly?

Comment: I don't understand your map. How is your map defined in Go? What you have shown us isn't valid Go code. What is it?

Comment: my map is personMap := make(map[string]string). Using this I created by personMap := [01:aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccc123456]. And I want to the populate the value in the map into my Person Struct... and then call jsResp, _ := json.Marshal(PersonStructPtr) to create the JSON object... Does this clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

That's not `json` data. However, the `binary.Read` function will decode arbitrary fixed sized values from a binary stream following the struct layout.

```
data := []byte("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaccccccccccccccc123456")
err := binary.Read(bytes.NewReader(data), binary.LittleEndian, &p)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-I_XhUCvNN

Comment: This worked.. Thanks very much @JimB. But I have another followup if you can help...

Comment: Ok So I am not able to add lot of data in the comments it seems ... @JimB can you please look at my follow up question at the link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941841/golang-populate-array-of-structure